# Help in convolution operation

Tags: self-study, image-processing, convolution

I am stuck in understanding how the output of convolution operation is obtained. Can somebody please show the steps? The question is an image is processed by applying 3*3 mean filter . What is the impulse response?

The formula is $g(m,n) = \sum_{\alpha = 0}^{M-1} \sum_{\beta=0}^{N-1} f(\alpha,\beta)h(m-\alpha,n-\beta)$

The image function $f$ =

```
                         0 0 0 0 0
                         0 1 1 1 0
                         0 1 1 1 0
                         0 1 1 1 0
                         0 0 0 0 0

h = 1 1 1
    1 1 1
    1 1 1
```

The result of the operation (obtained in Matlab) is g(m,n) =

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
0 2 4 6 4 2 0
0 3 6 9 6 3 0
0 2 4 6 4 2 0
0 1 2 3 2 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I cannot understand the steps how to do it in paper, can somebody please show the few steps how to go about it ?

Based on the reply and the formula, I have worked out one example, but the answers don't match with the formula and the other technique. For convolution at pixel f(0,0) the answer = 0. But I am getting 0 using the formula and 1 using the drag method. The cell to which this result will be mapped is g(0,0) and I have put the answer there.

For convolution of pixel element at f(1,1) = 1 also, when I evaluated I am getting answer 2 instead of 4. The result should go to g(2,2). But how do I get values for g(5,0) since the original image f has no fifth row!! How to calculate values for fifth and sixth rows?
Please let me know what is wrong in my understanding. Is my coordinate system incorrect? Shall really appreciate.
[image]

Comment: I published an illustrated explanation of convolution on the Web at http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution/129753, http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution-part-2-of-3/129751, and http://www.directionsmag.com/features/convolution-part-3-of-3/129750.

Comment: @whuber:THank you for the link, it is really interesting reading it.I am unable to solve the problem of convolution & posted the working of it.Simply unable to follow the answer inspite of the illustration :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image convolution applies a convolution mask `h` to the image. Let's start by aligning the center of the mask with the 1 in the top lefthand corner. I've added a star to set it off.

```
                     0  0  0  0  0
                     0 *1  1  1  0
                     0  1  1  1  0
                     0  1  1  1  0
                     0  0  0  0  0
```

To compute the convolution at that point, you multiply the mask by the neighborhood of that point.

In this case, the neighborhood is:

```
                     0  0  0
                     0 *1  1
                     0  1  1
```

Then, using the mask

```
                 h = 1  1  1
                     1  1  1
                     1  1  1
```

then the value of the convolution at that point will be the pointwise product of the mask and the neighborhood

```
                     0(1) + 0(1) + 0(1) + 
                     0(1) + 1(1) + 1(1) +
                     0(1) + 1(1) + 1(1) = 4
```

That 4 corresponds to the point below I've set off in brackets.

```
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                   0 1 2 3 2 1 0
                   0 2[4]6 4 2 0
                   0 3 6 9 6 3 0
                   0 2 4 6 4 2 0
                   0 1 2 3 2 1 0
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

If we look at the post-convolution image, we see that the point we just found is at (2,2), whereas the point in the original image is at (1,1). Why is there an extra column and row? It's caused by 2 factors:

1. The coordinate of the output is defined by the location of the center of the convolution mask.
2. The mask only needs to overlap the original image at a single point.

The location of the output in the convolution is the location of the center of the convolution mask.  I've marked all the legal locations for the center of the convolution mask with a `*`.

```
                  -* -* -* -* -* -* -*
                  -* 0* 0* 0* 0* 0* -*
                  -* 0*[1*]1* 1* 0* -*
                  -* 0* 1* 1* 1* 0* -*
                  -* 0* 1* 1* 1* 0* -*
                  -* 0* 0* 0* 0* 0* -*
                  -* -* -* -* -* -* -*
```

Our point of interest (the `1` in the upper left) is now at (2,2) in the grid of legal locations for the center of the convolution, which tells us the output of the convolution at this point should be at (2,2).

You can think of the convolution as "moving" along the image. Let's say the next point evaluated is the one to the right of our starting point:

```
                     0  0  0  0  0
                     0  1 *1  1  0
                     0  1  1  1  0
                     0  1  1  1  0
                     0  0  0  0  0
```

The value of the convolution at this point is again, the neighborhood times the mask:

```
                     0(1) + 0(1) + 0(1) + 
                     1(1) + 1(1) + 1(1) +
                     1(1) + 1(1) + 1(1) = 6
```

Which corresponds to this point in the resulting image:

```
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
                   0 1 2 3 2 1 0
                   0 2 4[6]4 2 0
                   0 3 6 9 6 3 0
                   0 2 4 6 4 2 0
                   0 1 2 3 2 1 0
                   0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

The convolution is evaluated at every potential overlapping point between the image and the mask, which is why the resulting convolution is larger than the original image. The 0 in the top right-hand corner is the result of convolving just the top right point of the image (0) with just the bottom left corner of the convolution.

Comment: Thank you for your illustration.But the thing which still confuses me is which coordinate do you apply the output of the result?Say, when the result is 4, why is 4 put in third row, third column of the 7*7 matrix?Same for the value 6 in third row and fourth column?How do I get to know which coordinate to place the value in?

Comment: Can you please explain this?

Comment: I've updated the explanation.

Comment: Thank you for so much effort,I must be really dumb not to understand still.I have worked it out and posted the answer.THe thing is when I apply the formula,it becomes tedious and the result does not match with the method that you described.In my class also we were taught the same technique which you have illustrated,but when asked to apply the formula,it gets all messed up.I don't understand where is the problem in my understanding & why I am doing it wrong.Could you please please go through the working out that I have uploaded.

Comment: Your method's right, you're just putting the number in the wrong box. The center of the convolution is at (0,0) in the original image, but not in the output, because the center of the convolution could be located outside the bounds of the original image.

The center of the convolution could be at the point (-1,-1) on the image you've drawn--do you follow that?

It may be helpful for you to think of the top left-hand point in the output of the convolution as (-1,-1) instead of (0,0)

Comment: The g(0,0) that I calculated should have gone to the actual (0,0) based on the input coordinate?Also, the range of the limit in the formula,should that be alpha,beta from zero to 4 instead of 6(incorrectly done by me on paper)?Whose coordinate does the alpha beta in the formula represent?So,if I use the formula,then I should be calculating g(0,0),g(0,1),g(0,2,),g(0,3),g(0,4),g(1,0) etc.Is my understanding now correct?Thank you once again for continued help.

Comment: Ah, okay. Your formula should be $g(m-1,n-1)$ instead of $g(m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zhrrkSGnM8) explains convolution quite nicely. Different number examples, but you'll see how the dot product works.